# Launch django unittest with a new database

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-1.9, enforcement

The question is in the title.

How can I run the unit tests with `manage.py test` from the command line without having to type yes if an old test database hasn't been destroyed(this happens when the tests are aborted).

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`--noinput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---noinput) option (`--no-input` is an alternative alias in Django 1.9+).

```
./manage.py test --noinput
```